# Pasar los datos que estan en un txt de un tablero a ciertas casillas de un array

Tags: c++

Tengo que hacer un tablero de un juego en c++. Para hacerlo los datos de las casillas "especiales" se encuentran en un documento de texto cuyas columnas contienen cada una el numero de la casilla donde debe ir la casilla especial y el nombre de la casilla.

```
5 OCA
9 OCA
6 PUENTE1
12 PUENTE2
14 OCA
15 NORMAL
18 OCA
19 POSADA
23 OCA
26 DADO1
27 OCA
30 NORMAL
31 POZO
32 OCA
36 OCA
41 OCA
42 LABERINTO
45 OCA
50 OCA
52 CARCEL
53 DADO2
54 OCA
58 CALAVERA
59 OCA
0
```

El problema es que tablero es un array de un tipo definido.
El subprograma que he hecho no funciona correctamente, ya que no guarda en el array lo que pone en el fichero, tiene que guardar en el puesto del array que toque el tipo de casilla que es, en el caso de 5 OCA, tiene que guardar en tablero[5] el tipo OCA, y llevo 2 dias dandole vueltas y buscando soluciones pero no las encuentro.

```
typedef enum { NORMAL, OCA, PUENTE1, PUENTE2, POZO, POSADA, LABERINTO, DADO1, DADO2, CARCEL, CALAVERA } tCasilla;
typedef tCasilla tTablero[CASILLA_META];

bool cargaTablero(tTablero tablero) {
    ifstream archivo("oca.txt");
    if (archivo.is_open()) {
        string nombre;
        //int num;
        int i = 0;
        while (getline(archivo, nombre)) {
           
                if (nombre == "OCA") {
                    tablero[i] = OCA;
                }
                else if (nombre == "PUENTE1") {
                    tablero[i] = PUENTE1;
                }
                else if (nombre == "PUENTE2") {
                    tablero[i] = PUENTE2;
                }
                else if (nombre == "POZO") {
                    tablero[i] = POZO;
                }
                else if (nombre == "POSADA") {
                    tablero[i] = POSADA;
                }
                else if (nombre == "CARCEL") {
                    tablero[i] = CARCEL;
                }
                else if (nombre == "CALAVERA") {
                    tablero[i] = CALAVERA;
                }
                i++;
        } 
        archivo.close();
        return true;
    }
    else {
        cout << "EL ARCHIVO NO SE PUDO ABRIR" << endl;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: No entiendo el problema, puedes dar mas detalle?

Comment: Hola Dwogur, bienvenido, si no explicas a que te refieres con "no funciona correctamente", es muy difícil que alguien pueda ayudarte, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y expliques cual es el mal funcionamiento a que te refieres, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta, explicando lo que debe hacer el programa. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código tiene ciertos ... *problemillas*:

- En C++, los `enum` son cosas numéricas. **No** puedes sacar directamente la cadena equivalente a un valor de un `enum`; tienes que usar *cosas* auxiliares.
- Tienes un archivo de texto con un formato dado ... que no estás usando para nada. ¿ Por qué leer línea a línea ? Puedes leer elemento a elemento.
- Como dijimos en el punto anterior, no lees los campos de archivos. Lees línea a línea ... que tendrás que *procesar* para extraer los campos.

Un código que **si** hace lo que pretendes, basado en el tuyo:

```
typedef enum { NORMAL, OCA, PUENTE1, PUENTE2, POZO, POSADA, LABERINTO, DADO1, DADO2, CARCEL, CALAVERA } tCasilla;
typedef tCasilla tTablero[CASILLA_META];

string Nombres[] = { "NORMAL", "OCA", "PUENTE1", "PUENTE2", "POZO", "POSADA", "LABERINTO", "DADO1", "DADO2", "CARCEL", "CALAVERA" };

tCasilla texto2Enum( const std::string &text ) {
    for( size_t idx = 0; idx < ( sizeof( Nombres ) / sizeof( Nombres[0] ) ); ++idx ) {
        if( text == Nombres[idx] ) { return tCasilla( int( idx ) ); }
    }

    return tCasilla::NORMAL;
}

tTablero Tablero = { tCasilla::NORMAL };

bool cargaTablero( tTablero tablero ) {
    ifstream archivo( "oca.txt" );

    if( archivo.is_open( ) ) {
        while( true ) {
            int index;
            archivo >> index;
            if( !archivo ) { break; }
            string typeName;
            archivo >> typeName;
            if( !archivo ) { break; }

            tablero[index] = texto2Enum( typeName );
        }

        return true;
    }

    cout << "EL ARCHIVO NO SE PUDO ABRIR" << endl;
    return false;
}
```

Verás que hay ciertas operaciones de *forzado* tipos relacionadas con tu `enum`. C++ es bastante *puntilloso* con los tipos. Si una cosa es `enum`, **no** es un entero. Y viceversa.

Tenemos una función auxiliar que, dado una cadena, nos devuelve el elemento de `tCasilla` correspondiente (por brevedad, no hay control de errores. **Cuidadín**).

Leemos el archivo aprovechando que tiene un formato: índice de la casilla y tipo.

Insisto en que no hay ningún control de errores: ni sobre el tipo de casilla, ni sobre el índice de la misma.

Comment: Gracias, pero hay cosas que no entiendo.
size_t idx = 0; idx < ( sizeof( Nombres ) / sizeof( Nombres[0] ) ); ++idx
el bucle for, idx tiene que ser menor que nombres, siendo nombres el numero de casillas que hay, que seria 63 o el numero de tipos, NORMAL, OCA, etc que hay?
y Nombres, seria un tipo tCasilla?

Comment: @Dwogur él creó un arreglo `string Nombres[]` con los nombres de los enums para hacer lo que tu estabas haciendo dentro del `while` más legible. La expresión de 2 `sizeof` divididos te permite calcular el tamaño del arreglo.

Comment: Es verdad, no lo habia visto, muchas gracias a los 2, parece que funciona correctamente

Comment: Los enumerados tradicionales sí son enteros (se pueden convertir implícitamente a entero), los enumerados de C++11 no lo son (se prohíbe la conversión implícita a entero).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Cierto ... se me olvida que hubo cosas antes de C++11 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como [ha mencionado Trauma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/595280/2742), no hay una conversión directa de un valor enumerado a un literal de texto. Al menos no hasta que se apruebe [especificación técnica `reflexpr` de C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/reflexpr) (tal vez en C++26).

Hasta entonces, puedes hacer algún truco como guardar pares de valor ⇄ texto en un par de mapas:

```
// En C++ los enumerados son tipos básicos, no necesitas el 'typedef'
enum tCasilla { NORMAL, OCA, PUENTE1, PUENTE2, POZO, POSADA, LABERINTO, DADO1, DADO2, CARCEL, CALAVERA };

template <typename enum_t> requires std::is_enum_v<enum_t>
std::map<enum_t, std::string> nombre;

template <typename enum_t> requires std::is_enum_v<enum_t>
std::map<std::string, enum_t> valor;

/* Por cada par de 'enumerado' con 'texto' añade los valores
en los mapas 'nombre' y 'valor'. */
template <typename enum_t, typename ...pack> requires std::is_enum_v<enum_t>
void configura(enum_t a_valor, const std::string &a_nombre, pack ...a_valores)
{
    if constexpr ((sizeof...(pack) != 0) && ((sizeof...(pack) % 2) == 0))
    {
        nombre<enum_t>[a_valor] = a_nombre;
        valor<enum_t>[a_nombre] = a_valor;
        configura(a_valores ...);
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Indicamos pares de valor y nombre.
    configura
    (
        NORMAL, "NORMAL",
        OCA, "OCA",
        PUENTE1, "PUENTE1",
        PUENTE2, "PUENTE2",
        POZO, "POZO",
        POSADA, "POSADA",
        LABERINTO, "LABERINTO",
        DADO1, "DADO1",
        DADO2, "DADO2",
        CARCEL, "CARCEL",
        CALAVERA, "CALAVERA"
    );

    for (const auto &[k, v] : nombre<tCasilla>)
        std::cout << v << " = " << k << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior [produce la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##rVNNj9MwED3Hv2Iwoptos9Vujv2SQpsDUmlRWTiwrCKTOpXVxAmJEy2s@tcJ/ko2BwQXLvb4zbPfjP2clOVNkhF@6rrXjCdZc6SwyEm5Qi/LWlSMn8aI@FHSWFSEiXoMs0JSKclXCFHe5CDWpGZZRuAZdvvD@3Drw34d@vDhU7S7j@76IJDB/stejR/Djcxvw7fR4d3uXkKbcLO/M5OkrcPDOtqqeRt@jg4hXOYICZqXGRG2LE5yCko9Fiuo6PeGVbSGWhxnM1bHOtEubB5pWHZrAd/wbL/Ai/xbRf@Twuhkf9jdkqyo/ibgwwBMp9OSJOd/S7YFO0JS8JSdmoq4BgYSazFfZWoxbhQmJDat@qAUlJJl09pDz8hhqdlFn8oKXLdmP2mRSpar6B68WsKtB5PJH1JvIPBgqfIecuRJjhHqa32wOo@whL6IuWRpcEQyGcOyd@Y4Ly0O1arSPZm7oAtCjAvICeOu7mFgI8eVm3s/YhNgX2Lam1iOejWYFNtohAYDGhhU2xerya6NkbEJNDYyNR5inbEex3oekMAiRqF3PjaBxcwv0KgJMXJk/8hJC/lQ5qVJIwqYPJx9aB9hZk296L/mSr6Lo82QFI2AxQJaNWB51VgFZzVcfeVX6tSKiqbicDtHl677laQZOdXdjdy9TK6vA/Ib):

> ```
> NORMAL = 0
> OCA = 1
> PUENTE1 = 2
> PUENTE2 = 3
> POZO = 4
> POSADA = 5
> LABERINTO = 6
> DADO1 = 7
> DADO2 = 8
> CARCEL = 9
> ```

Usando esa utilidad sobre tu código, podría quedar así:

```
constexpr std::size_t CASILLA_META = 60;
using tTablero = tCasilla[CASILLA_META]; // 'using' es más claro que 'typedef'.

/* Uso un stream de entrada genérico para poder leer de archivo,
de texto, de consola o de cualquier flujo de entrada */
void cargaTablero(std::istream &i, tTablero &tablero)
{
    int index{};
    std::string typeName{};

    /* Si falla al leer 'index' o si 'index' es 0 o
    si falla al leer 'typeName' dejamos de leer. */
    while ((i >> index) && index && (i >> typeName))
        tablero[index] = valor<tCasilla>[typeName];
}

int main()
{
    configura
    (
        NORMAL, "NORMAL",
        OCA, "OCA",
        PUENTE1, "PUENTE1",
        PUENTE2, "PUENTE2",
        POZO, "POZO",
        POSADA, "POSADA",
        LABERINTO, "LABERINTO",
        DADO1, "DADO1",
        DADO2, "DADO2",
        CARCEL, "CARCEL",
        CALAVERA, "CALAVERA"
    );

    tTablero t{};

    std::stringstream i{datos};
    cargaTablero(i, t);

    for (int index = 0; index != CASILLA_META; ++index)
        std::cout << "tablero[" << index << "] = " << t[index] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVRNb9pAED17f8XUVYkRTgQm0CQQJJdwiESgIrSH0ghtjKGrGpvaS5oW8ddLZ3fWxpGq9tKLd/xmdufrzQSbzWkQ8Xh1OLwWcRBtFyF013zTY8ffTKYiXpUR@WMTzmXKhcxeGKJlyNdlSCQ5xsJ4uwbZ55mIIg47GI0nd/7QhXHfd@H9h8FoOmjkgofC@NNYfe/9G9QP/XeDye1oitCNfzNu0IFmfX/SHwzVOfQ/DiY@7DuMBUmcyfB5k0ImF1dXmfiJ4aLJ/e1w6M/vBlMfrqFd77BthpmBnPLHKEwTBPP4ZmXjB3xShutNxKVJPubrEFRCc9mDNPy2FWmYkTORzbXiqWv0TMNYUwO4JiiqKsTJ@jEN/5OH0stucfuJR0n6NwcuFMDZ2dmGB1//7fIpEQvAOi/Faptyh2Dgc@3MBd2BcqJQ4XNK1QXlQXky1mFWZTtmiSUc@@Y4qmnJEq0cZV6FV9dQr0Kl8gfVG/CqcK30VWbhSxY5ymOdGT8P2N88iA5aabBkRBqyMjWzrGOKRbQq9Crq9mzPTB14uuKGRI4pmKY9VIR7pFdFkkDpxhJEvAifd8hYq1wp1YwRNkMpmPX9i4hCTFpAr0cXdBW0pMuhFfkdVQHLuJlpG5UPZZpzuzfLrZHYezMtL3q14DLJ8N7EdlpqPtml/rbzMWUNLx9U1jjXukbLDDRrXBBwaYaXeU0NeG0aXea91f/Nen6j2dDTzpoeKdr6OG/Q4R2Hn51TOK06HZ4Zf9Zq0j5gLYqmdVEsBNai4OtVG8upqr7mInZ0D4rmMsvBuuUbySbBdhHT28nGr/4r1pRtpBLqFahHqF5gtjrMP60ymwSNldaaXchaY7acrc8C8QxCHvLdZ5NgMEpboyTazKoqJhU8lMSsUscNW8VOd14R8gWlFYn1E8sER7NgLjKk3jEijmd5ZXagViOyYkzaUZBsJXS7YOfstNUfXVaw4qmGZM5blE8@xyfKbxrKbRqjN7Y/HH4Fy4ivssMpvnsd1Goe/w0)</kbd>.