# Cargar datos de un documento txt

Tags: c++

Necesito que cargue los datos de un archivo, en un tipo struct. El archivo de texto es de este estilo:

```
4 OCA
5 POSADA
13 PUENTE1
17 OCA
19 DADO1
20 CARCEL
21 OCA
24 LABERINTO
27 PUENTE2
29 OCA
32 OCA
35 CALAVERA
36 POZO
38 OCA
42 OCA
43 DADO2
44 OCA
47 OCA
50 OCA
53 OCA
58 OCA
63 OCA
0
2
12 0
1 3
```

Lo que debe hacer el subprograma es cargar los datos de la partida en un tablero, las casillas que pone, como 4 OCA o cosas asi, son las casillas especiales, el 0 que hay antes del 2 es para saber donde termina el tablero y donde empieza la situación de los jugadores, el subprograma para leer el tablero funciona, pero para leer los jugadores no se como hacerlo. El 1er nº después del 0 es el turno del jugador que debe tirar a continuación, los jugadores están guardados cada uno en una fila, el 1er nº de la fila es la casilla donde esta el jugador, el 2º es el numero de penalizaciones que tiene.

```
void cargaJugadores(tEstadoJugadores& jugadores, ifstream& archivo) {
    string nombres;
    if (archivo.is_open()) {
        while(true){
            archivo >> nombres;
            if (nombres == "0") {
                for (int i = 0; i < NUM_JUGADORES; i++) {                  
                    archivo >> jugadores[i].casilla;
                    archivo >> jugadores[i].penalizaciones;
                }
            }
        }
        
        archivo.close();
    }
}
```

Partidas[1], en vez de tener un uno deberia tener un contador de partidas, pero eso no lo he implementado aun, y para el turno tengo el codigo asi y tampoco funciona:

```
bool cargaPartidas(tListaPartidas& partida) {
    string nombre;
    cout << "Introduce el nombre del archivo: ";
    cin >> nombre;
    ifstream archivo(nombre);

    if (!archivo.is_open()) {
        cout << "No se pudo abrir el archivo de partidas." << endl;
        return false;
    }
    else if (archivo.is_open()) {
        while (true) {
            int datos;
            archivo >> datos;
            if (datos == 0) {
                archivo >> partida.partidas[1].turno;
                break;
            }
        }
        cargaTablero2(partida.partidas[1].tablero, archivo);
        cargaJugadores(partida.partidas[1].estadoJug, archivo);

        archivo.close();
        return true;
    }
   
}
```

Comment: No entiendo el problema.  ¿Y por qué `partidas[1]` en lugar de iterar sobre todas las partidas?

Comment: @Mateo he cambiado un poco la pregunta, espero que se entienda mejor ahora, si tienes alguna idea de como hacerlo, agradecería que me la comentases porque tengo un bloqueo espectacular con esto.

Comment: Si no me equivoco, en tu bucle `for` de `cargaJugadores` no estás teniendo en cuenta la línea que contiene `2`. Diría que `jugadores[0].casilla` valdrá `2` en vez de `12`.

Comment: @JorgeLuis El problema es que para jugadores no toma ningun valor, y me da error como que no se han inciado jugadores

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de contenedor son `tListaPartidas` y `tEstadoJugadores`? ¿Estás seguro de que en  `cargaPartidas` quieres rellenar la segunda partida (de índice 1) en vez de la primera?

Answer (score 2):

Estás describiendo un proceso de [serialización](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializaci%C3%B3n). Una de las maneras "*elegantes*" de serializar en C++ es mediante la sobrecarga de los operadores de lectura y escritura en flujo de datos. Según tu descripción necesitas gestionar tres datos:

1. Estado del tablero.
2. Turno de la partida.
3. Estado de los jugadores.

Así que vamos a definir unos objetos para gestionar estos datos:

```
enum tCasilla { NORMAL, OCA, PUENTE1, PUENTE2, POZO, POSADA, LABERINTO, DADO1, DADO2, CARCEL, CALAVERA };

constexpr std::size_t CASILLA_META = 60;
// Tablero es una formacion de 60 elementos de tipo tCasilla
using Tablero = tCasilla[CASILLA_META];

struct Jugador
{
    int casilla{};
    int penalizaciones{};
};

struct Partida
{
    Tablero tablero{};
    int turno{}
    Jugador jugador[2]{};
};
```

Una vez tenemos los datos, definimos la sobrecarga de los operadores de lectura de datos (que es lo que tienes dudas en esta pregunta):

```
// Lector de tablero
std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &i, Tablero &t)
{
    int index{};
    std::string typeName{};

    /* Si falla al leer 'index' o si 'index' es 0 o
    si falla al leer 'typeName' dejamos de leer. */
    while ((i >> index) && index && (i >> typeName))
        t[index] = valor<tCasilla>[typeName];

    return i;
}

// Lector de jugador
std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &i, Jugador &j)
{
    i >> j.casilla;
    i >> j.penalizaciones;

    return i;
}

// Lector de partida
std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &i, Partida &p)
{
    i >> p.tablero;
    i >> p.turno;
    for (auto &j : p.jugador)
        i >> j;

    return i;
}
```

Con estos preparativos, la lectura de tus datos podría parecerse a esto:

```
/* Uso un stringstream por comodidad, podria ser un ifstream y funcionaria
sin cambiar el codigo. */
std::stringstream ss{datos};

Partida p;
ss >> p;

std::cout << "La partida esta en el turno " << p.turno << '\n';
for (int i = 0; i != 2; ++i)
    std::cout << "El jugador " << (i + 1) << " esta en la casilla "
            << p.jugador[i].casilla << " con "
            << p.jugador[i].penalizaciones << " penalizaciones.\n";
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVXdctpGFL7WPsUJniIpEAICO42xmVFtLtIhxoNpx1PiYTZicZcKSSMtaRIPD5Vn6HuVnt2jFTBuZ9rpjfbs@d/v/CjKsldRzJPH3e5EJlG8WQi4kGmhcsHXA7bnFc9Za54NGBPJZg3qihcyjjk8wc148j4cNWF8FTbh9qfhzXTYsUSAxPiXsf7ehdcoH4U/DCfvbqbIug6vxx06UO0qnFwNR/ochT8PJyFs@4xFaVIo8TnLoVCL8/NCfhVzhSp370ajcP5@OA3hEs7afbYpZPIIU/4xFnmKPJve7FD3AT3iozaRgh83j3yR5uyJOTJREJH2E8Y090wkPJZfeSTTRBSavd3b3vJcyQXXtjagorOyV5s8oVsZCFZ0zoIH602JdRZzhbCqLzreWoBGdq4GzDwWwb4gRrN8vcrxkQNI0vXHXPxLDweWTSuFTzxOc3Tw@iXcYm4RX3DIeA5YY1friBxzdQHRBxfhV0jzP75xFMdpQdaiwD4wV4zCC3ApKxe@gGsU3Ba8fP3PKTahYrRarYxHvw3Yp1QudNClfNzk3CNF4HPjrwmmGQ6hgDqfU9gmaA/aU6ktCt/Udgn7FvI83T/pErU8re7Di0to@1Cv/43oOwh8uNRynznoyaFAZUUGszLOA/aaTQKr7RjmgRJJSKtE3XH2T6yy1an7KNuyLaPiSRo/qKcZlkNhmQYD71gim1XH15Vve1kmC/HZ9N4hVBrtG0RbC5iDhb@TsOR6gHkMsRA5uMbQhRQKWV0wszak6OqZtnXoYtes@BobQbcHikzdnd9/lbFAXCWmTSkZoA1lEDcC60SD7KiZkWqwCEY7xIOZ1dMT7ORCjxfI/n/Eyo5ifUVY6QRWrXL0@xXjePb/T8ByUUA92wfMWuWu6O8ZelngdYluPL5RWM0VnKOg3BkaG8rtWTI0EsZmgWkUCN2k5vX0Kman5c5lna7dyqzzxog6b2n5sqBd7l0WdIwk6O03NAve2C3OgrdG3A3oOK3WNOuemQ3Put8bUY80el3a66xHyfQo8Gmbji4dZHJGtzYLWCeANutA16/hU08WYikTAVPv3of7JpzcM6YbfM1l4hlE94M09egv5ONIeOjNnOWrD@iAaMy3JDRAhqxebW4GnYoiKwKqJOnxvq8rcjBmZfGL4smUw8ya7YJMT2RhSl5ZRelGwcUF1EZmARs9USj8JCBi@o1ATWuUbaJJ90Pi2nYxA49Vb/fxwHUW9KHRkLpjjv0PY/sHInc4fg3o@EZWRcTxLqfBxrR/Lflg54Qs9J/hucrx5JDmMa/1IakdNDH@uLe73Z/RMuaPxe4VpnwZNRoB/ws)</kbd>. Parte del código está basado en [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/595313/2742).